# How to keep Workspaces in Blender 2.80 when opening previous version of blender's files?

Tags: interface, workspaces

[image: blender 2.7x bmps in blender 2.80]

i'd like to use the bmps file from previous version of blender, in blender 2.80 as latest version.

but, when it's opened, blender 2.80 lost every interface layout it usually has. especially those new workspaces as tabs on top of the screen.

is there a way to keep blender 2.80's interface layout -especially the workspaces- whenever we open previous version of blender files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Start new project using *General* preset
   [image]
2. *File* -> *Open ..*, locate your .blend, but before you open the file, **uncheck the Load UI** option

[image]

3. Your old .blend should be opened using the *General* preset UI, so the workspace should be there

Comment: thank you very much, Jan. 
didn't know nor paid attention to those two options below the open blender file's dialogue.

Comment: @irwan I am happy I could help you! :)